# optional variable argument to a constructor

Tags: python, constructor, set, optional-arguments

I tried to create a set constructor which can accept an optional variable argument

```
def __init__(self,*initElements = None)
```

But it gave me the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at this line. I thought this constructor will take some argument or set it to be None if no  argument is given. How can I deal with this problem? Could anyone give me a helping hand? 
Thanks^^

Comment: Perhaps tag your question with what language you are using.

Comment: The `*initElements=None` is invalid. In Python the asterisk usage in `*initElements` indicates [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). If you want to specify optional arguments you don't need the `=None` part, just leave it as `*initElements`, or more the standard used `*args`